# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'evalf'

Tags: python, google-colab

Soy nuevo en Python, estuve prácticando con funciones de una varible pero cuando ejecuto el código me sale un error (AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'evalf'). No encontre ningún tema igual en la página, así que decidí formular la pregunta yo mismo. Acá está el código:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol ('x')
y = -0.005*x**5 + 0.12*x**3 +0.01*x**2 - 0.12*x + 0.7
print('FUNCIÓN: y = ', y)
print()
print()

print('MÁXIMOS Y MÍNIMOS')
d1 = diff(y, x)
critical_points = list(solveset(d1))
d2 = diff(y, x, 2)
for i in [0,1,2,3]:
  p = (critical_points[i], y.subs({x:critical_points[i]}).evalf())
  m = d2.subs(({x:critical_points[i]}).evalf()) 
  if m > 0 :
    print('P', i+1, ':', p, 'MIN')
  else :
    print('P', i+1, ':', p, 'MAX') 

print()
print()


print('PUNTOS DE INFLEXIÓN')
inflex_points = list(solveset(d2))
for i in [0,1,2]:
  p= (inflex_points[i], y.subs({x:inflex_points[i]}).evalf())
 
  print('P', i+5, ':', p)
```

Comment: y que tratas de hacer con `.evalf()`??

Comment: Estoy tratando de evaluar la funcion

Comment: Evaluarla? De qué forma? A que te refieres?

Comment: Evaluarla para obtener los puntos criticos de la funcion.